# HttpRequest Post in Java

Tags: java, json, apache, javafx, httprequest

Created new API in java. I want to use this API's method like post,get methods but could'nt work.Could you give me hint to use other way to do it.

```
 URI url = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/departure/");
                System.out.println("koraylikchi");
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("departDate",dateChooser.getPromptText());
                jsonObject.put("time",timeField.getText());
                jsonObject.put("flight",flightField.getText());
                jsonObject.put("destination",destField.getText());
                jsonObject.put("statusTime",statusTimeField.getText());
                jsonObject.put("terminal",terminalField.getText());
                try {
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    int response = client.executeMethod((HttpMethod) httpPost);
                    System.out.println(response);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (HttpException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
```

But I get following errors

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod
    at controllers.AddDialogDepatureController.lambda$onClick$7(AddDialogDepatureController.java:190)
    at controllers.AddDialogDepatureController$$Lambda$413/1162975584.handle(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
```

Please could you give me hint? Can I do HTTPRequest in other way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
HttpClient client =  HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/departure/");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("departDate",dateChooser.getPromptText());
jsonObject.put("time",timeField.getText());
jsonObject.put("flight",flightField.getText());
jsonObject.put("destination",destField.getText());
jsonObject.put("statusTime",statusTimeField.getText());
jsonObject.put("terminal",terminalField.getText());
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
postRequest.setEntity(se);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer But when I try to implement your code it's give's following it give hint in first row of your code                  CloseableHttpClient client =  HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Comment: @JahongirSabirov `CloseableHttpClient` is a class that implements `HttpClient` . Did you try it? Let me know the error you're getting now.

Comment: Yes sir it works somehow but still I can't get result of posting httpRequest. I mean my javaFX application just keep loading.Nothing happens in server

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixt  What will be Get Request of this request ?